# example of HTMLElement.addEventListener in typescript?

Tags: typescript

can I get one? this is what I have, but I'm getting a red squiggly line:

```
let button = <HTMLElement>document.body.querySelector(".btn");
button.addEventListener("click", () =>{});//not sure what to do here.  I know its wrong though.
```

below is my tsonconfig

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom"
        ]
    },
    "include": [ "**/*" ]
}
```

Comment: The code compiles well in playground, what's your `tsconfig.json` file?

Comment: @NitzanTomer added the tson.config

Comment: "A red squiggly line" Certainly hovering over that will give you an error message...

Comment: It compiles fine for me with your settings. As @MikeMcCaughan said, you should get an error message.

Comment: If you had strictNullChecks on, I could see a problem, since `querySelector` can return null. Otherwise, I'm not sure why your IDE is giving you a problem.

Comment: typescript file extension must be .ts/.tsx if you write a typescript with extension .js the idea can not resolve it is a typescript file. if you write a typescript with extension .ts may be some error of the javascript language level,you shoud set the language level of javascript to ecmascript6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was ReSharper.  I disabled the plugin and it worked fine.  For reference I have attached two picutres, the first with ReSharper enabled, and the second with it disabled.[image: resharper][image: noreshaper]

Answer (score 6):

With your given tsconfig.json it compiles fine:

```
let button = <HTMLElement>document.body.querySelector(".btn");
button.addEventListener("click", () => { });
```

[image]

Your IDE is lying. Works fine in VSCode / alm